# BestPractice: Defining and populating Collections

Tags: apex, map, bestpractice, collection

What is the best practice when using collections.

Example:

This snippet:

```
shortStudentMap = new Map<string,string>();
shortStudentMap.put('1', 'Student1');
shortStudentMap.put('2', 'Student2');
shortStudentMap.put('3', 'Student3');
shortStudentMap.put('4', 'Student4');
shortStudentMap.put('5', 'Student5');
shortStudentMap.put('6', 'Student6');
```

Or this snippet:

```
shortStudentMap = new Map<string,string>
{
     1 => 'Student1',
     2 => 'Student2',
     3 => 'Student3',
     4 => 'Student4',
     5 => 'Student5',
     6 => 'Student6'
};
```

Comment: The second one will be translated to the first format in the compiling time. The second one is good for typing, the first one is good for compiler

Comment: Would you mind updating the title so something more specific than "using" ? For instance "Defining and populating collections" may cover the content of your question better, making it more discoverable for otheres with the same question.

Comment: See the answer starting "The time reporting in the original code appears broken"; the performance difference between the two patterns is insignificant.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke better?

Comment: Definitely, thanks. I like questions like these, so i figured a more specific title would be good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The time reporting in the original code appears broken. (The code in the earlier answer.)

Running the code below shows that there isn't a significant difference in performance, both reporting 18 to 22 ms with the "=>" approach normally being faster than the "put" approach.

```
@isTest
Public Class speed{

    public void try1(){
        Map<string,string> shortStudentMap;
        shortStudentMap = new Map<string,string>();
        shortStudentMap.put('1', 'Student1');
        shortStudentMap.put('2', 'Student2');
        shortStudentMap.put('3', 'Student3');
        shortStudentMap.put('4', 'Student4');
        shortStudentMap.put('5', 'Student5');
        shortStudentMap.put('6', 'Student6');
    }

    public void try2(){
        Map<string,string> shortStudentMap = new Map<string,string> {
             '1' => 'Student1',
             '2' => 'Student2',
             '3' => 'Student3',
             '4' => 'Student4',
             '5' => 'Student5',
             '6' => 'Student6'
        };   
    }

    @isTest
    static void test() {

        Speed s = new Speed();

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(Integer i =0; i < 100; i++){
            s.try1();
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(Integer i =0; i < 100; i++){
            s.try2();
        }
        long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.debug('ms1=' + (t2 - t1));
        System.debug('ms2=' + (t4 - t3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hooray. That not only makes more sense, but means my preferred method is still the "best" if only very marginally.

Comment: Thank you for the correction Keith. I agree there is not much difference.

Comment: @KeithC have not noticed the datetime and currentTimeMillis, thank you for the correction

Answer (score 6):

> Bellow is not correct answer. For calculating time lapsed we should use System.currentTimeMillis() and not datetime.now() . For correct answer please refer Keith C post

Here is how:

Created a following class:

```
Public Class speed{

public void try1(){
    Map<string,string> shortStudentMap;
    shortStudentMap = new Map<string,string>();
    shortStudentMap.put('1', 'Student1');
    shortStudentMap.put('2', 'Student2');
    shortStudentMap.put('3', 'Student3');
    shortStudentMap.put('4', 'Student4');
    shortStudentMap.put('5', 'Student5');
    shortStudentMap.put('6', 'Student6');
}

public void try2(){
Map<string,string> shortStudentMap;

shortStudentMap = new Map<string,string>
    {
         '1' => 'Student1',
         '2' => 'Student2',
         '3' => 'Student3',
         '4' => 'Student4',
         '5' => 'Student5',
         '6' => 'Student6'
    };
}     
}
```

And then run following code in developer console:

```
Speed s = new Speed();

datetime start1 = datetime.now();
for(Integer i =0; i < 100; i++){
    s.try1();
}
datetime end1 = datetime.now();
System.debug('Time Laps Try 1:' + (end1.getTime() - start1.gettime()));


datetime start2 = datetime.now();
for(Integer i =0; i < 100; i++){
    s.try2();
}
datetime end2 = datetime.now();
System.debug('Time Laps Try 2:' + (end2.getTime() - start2.gettime()));
```

I run above test many times and found that Try1 runs faster than try 2 every time.

So i would recommend you to use put method as best practice instead of providing large string to Slesforce . This will improve performance & readability of your code.

Comment: this great, I did not know about that.

Comment: you were right. 
1. `try 1 - 1:22` 
2. `try 2 - 2:23`

Comment: There used to be a strong reason for preferring the second way. When we were limited to 200k lines of code we could save some lines by initialising a map or list in a single line, but that is no longer the case. I still prefer the single-line method for neatness, but maybe I'll change now based on the performance difference you've found.

Comment: See my answer that starts with "The time reporting in the original code appears broken".

Comment: Now I have a ton of code to re-write... how naive of us developers to assume that the constructor would be faster.

Comment: @sfdcfox This accepted answer is wrong; the "=>" approach is faster than the "put" approach.

Comment: @KeithC have not tried your code, let me try it first. then I will change the correct answer for this question. fair enough?

Answer (score 2):

For Initializing the static data the following Snippet is useful but not for dynamic data..

```
shortStudentMap = new Map<string,string>
{
     1 => 'Student1',
     2 => 'Student2',
     3 => 'Student3',
     4 => 'Student4',
     5 => 'Student5',
     6 => 'Student6'
};
```

So Its best practice to use the following snippet to initialize with static data or add dynamic data.

```
shortStudentMap = new Map<string,string>();
shortStudentMap.put('1', 'Student1');
shortStudentMap.put('2', 'Student2');
shortStudentMap.put('3', 'Student3');
shortStudentMap.put('4', 'Student4');
shortStudentMap.put('5', 'Student5');
shortStudentMap.put('6', 'Student6');
```

Comment: I think if have a static data is better to use the first snippet, but if I want dynamic data I should use the second snippet. It is about whether your data is static or dynamic.

Comment: And also Compare to first snippet second snippet is better because Its easy and Simple to add/modify records.Performance wise also second snippet is fast.. so Its better to use Put method always..

Answer (score 2):

Surprising that there is a significant difference in performance.

But bear in mind that there are other factors than performance when judging "best" and the ability to initialize a map without having to create a variable that pollutes the scope and clutters the code is a good language feature that is missing from e.g. Java that is worth using sometimes e.g.:

```
     ...
     someMethod(new Map<string,string>{
             '1' => 'Student1',
             '2' => 'Student2',
             '3' => 'Student3'
              });
     someMethod(new Map<string,string>{
             '4' => 'Student4',
             '5' => 'Student5',
             '6' => 'Student6'
              });
     someMethod(new Map<string,string>{
             '7' => 'Student7',
             '8' => 'Student8',
             '9' => 'Student9'
              });
     ...

 public void someMethod(Map<Integer, String> m) {
     ...
 }
```

Comment: it is a matter of situation, if performance is highly required then I should use the first snippet I included.

Comment: @robertpeter07 Agreed. Worth keeping this in mind too http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization.

Comment: will keep this in mind